# Apache poi method to write data to an existing workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This is my class to read and write existing excel files. I have been calling these functions in the main class by passing the filePath and fileName.

```
   public class NewExcelFile {

    Workbook workbook;

    /******* Methods *******/
    // returns a workbook on giving the excel file's path and name
    public Workbook readExcel(String filePath, String fileName) {
        // Create object of File class to open xlsx file
        File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
        // Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Unable to find " + fileName + " in "
                    + filePath);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Workbook workbook = null;
        // Find the file extension by spliting file name in substring and
        // getting only extension name
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        // Check condition if the file is xlsx file
        if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")) {
            // If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Check condition if the file is xls file
        else if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
            // If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            try {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.workbook = workbook;
        return workbook;

    }

    public void writeExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName,
            String dataToWrite, int rowno) {

        System.out.println("WriteExcel" + filePath + " " + fileName + " "
                + sheetName + " " + dataToWrite + " " + rowno);

        Workbook newWorkbook = readExcel(filePath, fileName);
        Sheet sheet = newWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        System.out.println("Sheet: " + sheet.getSheetName());

        Cell resultcell;

        ******resultcell = sheet.getRow(rowno).createCell(8);
        resultcell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        resultcell.setCellValue(dataToWrite);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        if (dataToWrite == "P") {
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL);
            resultcell.setCellStyle(style);
        } else if (dataToWrite == "F") {
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL);
            resultcell.setCellStyle(style);
        }
        // Create an object of FileOutputStream class to create write data in
        // excel file
        File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // write data in the excel file and close output stream
        try {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in writing to file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

When I get a workbook in the main using readExcel and call this function:

```
Row row = testScriptsSheet.getRow(24);
```

I get the correct row and am able to call all functions on this row.But for the exact same row in the exact same sheet in the writeExcel(), I get a null pointer exception(the line preceded by *** in the code above). getRow() gives me null here. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, should I keep workbook as a data member and do`myNewExcelFile.workbook` whenever I need it or keep it as a variable returned from the readExcel in the main class?
Also I was wondering what is happening now that I am not closing the inputStream at the end of the readExcel function. I get the same error whether I close the inputStream or not.

EDIT - Adding the main function

```
public class NewDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting the framework");
    // initialise the workbook
    NewExcelFile testExecution = new NewExcelFile();
    testExecution.readExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\",
            "abc.xlsx");

    // initialise sheets of workbook
    Sheet testSuiteSheet = testExecution.workbook.getSheet("TestSuite");
    Sheet testScriptsSheet = testExecution.workbook.getSheet("TestCases");
    Row row = testScriptsSheet.getRow(24);//gives the correct row

    //calling writeExcel gives npe in that line


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `WorkbookFactory` for opening the workbook? Much much simpler than most of the code you've written. See the [POI quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) for an example

Comment: I was thrown this exception
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:148)
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:199)
 at NewNewExcelFile.writeExcel(NewNewExcelFile.java:79)
 at NewNewRunTestSteps.runCase(NewNewRunTestSteps.java:67)
 at NewNewRunTestSteps.runCase(NewNewRunTestSteps.java:27)
 at NewNewDriver.main(NewNewDriver.java:69)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow(int)) the getRow(int) method:

> Returns the logical row (not physical) 0-based. If you ask for a row
>   that is not defined you get a null. This is to say row 4 represents
>   the fifth row on a sheet.

So when a row is not defined, you must first create the row and then create the cell.

Comment: My 24 is 0-based. The row is also defined. I am able to read that exact row in the main using the workbook returned from the readExcel() function.

Comment: Are you sure that row has some data? If it does not, the row may not be defined.

Comment: It does. Printing it out on the main gives the xml also

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding it seems a conceptual error. Before calling `WriteExcel()` method, all the changes that you have made in main method are in buffer, not written in the excel sheet/workbook present in your harddisk. But in `WriteExcel()` method you are not passing the sheet or workbook you kept in buffer, but the address of the one physically present in the hard drive. So any change you have done in main function is not there, hence showing null pointer exception.

e.g. I have one workbook in say my D Drive, having value 1 in A0. Now I have programmatically made it 2 but not perform the write operation, and put the execution on hold. Meanwhile I went to my D drive and open the sheet there will be 1 not 2, as the updated value is in buffer, till I have perform write operation on that workbook.

Suggestion: Instead of passing the address of the workbook, why not you just pass the workbook you have used in main method.

UPDATE: Not the main method but `readExcel(String filePath, String fileName)` method actually.

Comment: I tried passing the workbook. Same error.
Also, I am not making any changes to the workbook in the main method. I was just reading the cells there. I was hoping to make writeExcel() to make the changes. What you says make sense, but then I don't know where to close the output and input streams.

Comment: Where are you got that `Row row = testScriptsSheet.getRow(24);` is throwing no error. If `Row row = newWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowno);`throws exception it precisely means that sheet has not such row. Can you provide some more information on that. Also `readExcel()` seems directly picking the file from harddrive, not from any method, so any update will not reflect on that.

Comment: Added the main function